# Python decorator error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I try to creating decorator using following code.

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        print 'inner called'
        return inner

foo = outer()
foo()
```

But it gives the error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Please solve my problem. Thanks..

Comment: Also, to be a decorator, `outer` should take the function to decorate as argument.

Comment: Yes this isn't really a decorator, it's really just a wrapper function at the moment

Comment: Sorry it's really wrapper function.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is the code you wanted:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        print 'inner called'
    return inner

foo = outer()
foo()
```

Your `return` was indented too far

Comment: what is scope of `inner` **??**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it's local to outer()

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan or any enclosing function

Comment: @danielkullmann and jamylak:  then how `inner()` can be called usring `foo()`, if once `outer()` terminated.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan because inner is just the name of the function, but not the function itself. The function itself is returned by outer(), and therefore available to callers of outer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `outer` is not terminated, it's only used once to create `inner`, then only `inner` is called, `inner` is a separate function that happens to have access to its scope